# Changing divs with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to change the position of a few `divs` using jquery. My main idea is that when I click the left arrow, the div assigned to the specific location swaps places with the one on the left, when I click it again it swaps places with the div further on the left. When I click the right arrow, the same thing happens but for elements on the right side.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type ="radio" name ="tabs" id = "tab-2">
<label for="tab-2"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" id="paper"></i><div class ="news">LATEST NEWS</div></label>
<div class ="tab-content-two">
    <h3 id="latest-news">Latest News</h3>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left" id="left"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" id="right"></i>

    <img src = "img/1.jpg" id ="first-img">
    <div class ="hilight" id="img-text">
        <h4 id="news">Latest News Story<br>Title Example</h4>
    </div>

    <img src ="img/2.jpg" id ="second-img">
    <div class ="hilight-two"id="img-text">
        <h4 id="news">Latest News Story<br>Title Example</h4>
    </div>

    <img src ="img/3.jpg" id ="third-img">
    <div class ="hilight-big" id ="full-text">
        <h4 id="news-big">Latest News Story<br>Title Example</h4>
        <p id="date">14/02/2016</p>
        <p id ="text-big">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br> 
            consectetur adipiscing elit.<br> 
            Phasellus imperdiet orci..
            <button type="button" id ="button-reading">CONTINUE READING <i class="fa fa-angle-right" id="reading"></button></i>
        </p>


    </div>

    <img src ="img/4.jpg" id ="fourth-img">
    <div class ="hilight-three"d="img-text">
        <h4 id="news">Latest News Story<br>Title Example</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jquery I'm trying to build in order to achieve this:

```
$( "left" ).click(function() {
  $( hilight-two ).replaceWith( "<div>" + $( text-big ).text() + "</div>" );
});

$( "right" ).click(function() {
  $( hilight-two ).replaceWith( "<div>" + $( text-big ).text() + "</div>" );
});
```

I've attached a JS Fiddle in order to have a better idea. 
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qu7cdwkt/)

Here is a poorly created drawing of how it looks in the original version as well:[image: Original Drawing]

Comment: Can you clarify again, when you click on the left image, what should happen?

Comment: when you click on the left arrow, the text with the pink background from the third image should swap with the one on the left. If you click it again, it should go to the first image. Same thing goes for the right arrow but for the right side.

Comment: `$( "left" )` and `$( "right" )` can't be found, as they aren't tags. Use `$( "#left" )` and `$( "#right" )` to get items by `id`. For items with `class="hilight-two"` use `$('.hilight-two')`. The same for items with class="text-big"

Comment: The selectors aren't valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made hilight a class to group all the divs and modified your click handlers to

```
$( "#left" ).click(function() {
  var news = $(".hilight");
  var head = news.first().html();
  var length = news.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
      news.eq(i).html(news.eq(i + 1).html());
  }
  news.eq(length - 1).html(head);
});

$( "#right" ).click(function() {
     var news = $(".hilight");
   var tail = news.last().html();
   var length = news.length;
   for(var i = length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
       news.eq(i).html(news.eq(i - 1).html());
   }
   news.eq(0).html(tail);
});
```

I changed your css and your html a bit to use more classes and less id's.
Here is the updated JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/qu7cdwkt/5/

Hopefully this will get you started